# Adding imports to a class in java

Tags: java, bytecode, javassist

I am having trouble at the moment with imports in javassist. I had a look at the Javassist Tutorial, where it said I should use the importPackages(String packagename) method, but when I tried that I am still getting the same error. However, it also says it doesn't affect the get(String classname) method, as I have been using.

My error is this:

```
[source error] no such class: String

javassist.CtNewMethod.make(CtNewMethod.java:79)
javassist.CtNewMethod.make(CtNewMethod.java:45)
RainbowBansTransAgent.Transformationer.transform(Transformationer.java:30)
RainbowBansTransAgent.Transformationer.transform(Transformationer.java:105)
sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(Unknown Source)
sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses0(Native Method)
sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses(Unknown Source)
RainbowBansTransAgent.TransAgent.premain(TransAgent.java:106)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(Unknown Source)
sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(Unknown Source)
```

I heard that javassist automatically imported the java.lang package, but wouldn't that mean that java.lang.String would automatically be imported?

I then tried to insert the code using fully qualified class names such as:

```
java.io.BufferedReader reader = new java.io.BufferedReader (new java.io.FileReader(new java.io.File("file.txt"));
java.lang.String a = reader.readline();
```

But that just changes from:

[source error] no such class: String

to:

[source error] no such class: java.lang.String

Here is my source code:

```
package RainbowBansTransAgent;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer;
import java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;

import javassist.CannotCompileException;
import javassist.CtClass;
import javassist.CtField;
import javassist.CtMethod;
import javassist.CtNewMethod;
import javassist.NotFoundException;

public class Transformationer implements ClassFileTransformer {

public byte[] transform(String arg1){
    try {
    ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("java.net.SocketAddress");
    this.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass("java.net.SocketAddress");
        CtClass cc = TransAgent.coldwater.get(arg1);
        if(cc.isFrozen()){
            BooleanKeys.frozen = true;
            return null;
        }else{
        cc.getClassFile().setMajorVersion(javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.JAVA_4);
        CtMethod m = cc.getDeclaredMethod("checkIfShouldDisconnect");
        String doublequote = String.valueOf('"'); 
        CtMethod method = CtNewMethod.make("public static java.lang.String getCauseOfBan(java.lang.String playername){"
    + "java.lang.String cause = " + doublequote + "Server" + doublequote + ";"
    + "try {"
    +   "java.io.BufferedReader reader = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader(new java.io.File(getRainbowPath()" +  doublequote + "banned-players.json" + doublequote + ")));"
    +   "java.nio.file.Path path = java.nio.file.Paths.get(getRainbowPath(), " + doublequote + "banned-players.json" + doublequote + ");"
    +   "byte[] filebytes = java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(path);"
    +   "java.lang.String ln = new java.lang.String(filebytes);"
    +   "java.lang.System.out.println(ln);"
    +   "int beginIndex = ln.indexOf(playername);"
    +   "if(beginIndex < 0){"
    +       "System.out.println(" + doublequote + "could not find" + doublequote + "playername" + ");"
    +       "reader.close();"
    +       "return " + doublequote + "Unknown" + doublequote + ";"
    +   "}"
    +   "java.lang.String plrln = ln.substring(beginIndex, ln.length());"
    +   "java.lang.String searchline = plrln.substring(0, plrln.indexOf(" + doublequote + "expires" + doublequote + "));"
    +   "cause = plrln.substring((searchline.indexOf(" + doublequote + "source" + doublequote + ") + 10), (searchline.length() - 8));"
    +   "reader.close();"
    +"} catch (java.io.IOException e) {"
    +   "e.printStackTrace();"
    + "}"
    + "return cause;"
    + "}", cc);
        CtField f = CtField.make("java.io.File banmessage = new java.io.File(" + doublequote + "RainbowBans + File.separatorChar" + doublequote + " banmessage.txt);", cc);
        CtField g = CtField.make("java.io.File adminplace = new java.io.File(" + doublequote + "banned-players.json" + doublequote + ");", cc);
        cc.addField(g);
        cc.addField(f);
        cc.addMethod(method);
        int n = m.insertAt(409, true, "{    java.io.BufferedReader reader = null;"
                                    + "     reader = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader(banmessage));"
                                    + "     java.lang.String message = reader.readLine();"
                                    + "     reader.close();"
                                    + "     java.lang.String admin = getCauseOfBan(var2.getName());" //NOT REALLY! A FOR LOOP IS NECESSARY! (if this works at all).
                                    + "     java.lang.String var4 = message.replaceAll(" + doublequote + "%REASON%" + doublequote + ", var5.d()).replaceAll(" + doublequote + "%CURRENTTIME%" + doublequote + ", new java.util.Date().toString()).replaceAll(" + doublequote + "%ADMIN%" + doublequote + ", admin);}");
        if(n == 409){
            BooleanKeys.returns_line = true;
            NumberKeys.line_Inserted_At = 409;
        }else{
            BooleanKeys.returns_line = false;
            NumberKeys.line_Inserted_At = n;
        }
        System.out.println("Code inserted at line " + n);
        return cc.toBytecode();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        BooleanKeys.error = true;
        TransAgent.ln.add(69125L);
    } catch (CannotCompileException e) {
        BooleanKeys.error = true;
        TransAgent.ln.add(31513169125L);
        TransAgent.randomexception = e;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        BooleanKeys.error = true;
        TransAgent.ln.add(14152061521144L);
    } catch (NotFoundException e) {
        BooleanKeys.error = true;
        TransAgent.ln.add(14152061521144L);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public byte[] transform(ClassLoader arg0, String className, Class<?> arg2,
        ProtectionDomain arg3, byte[] arg4)
        throws IllegalClassFormatException {
    BooleanKeys.transformer_loaded = true;
    byte[] b = null;
    String realName = className.replaceAll("/", ".");
    if(realName.equals("joebkt.PlayerList")){
        if(BooleanKeys.returned_bytes){
            return null;
        }else{
        BooleanKeys.found_class = true;
        b =  transform(realName);
        if(b !=null){
            BooleanKeys.returned_bytes = true;
        }
        }
    }
    else System.out.println("Class name " + realName + " is not what we're looking for!");
    return b;
}
```

}

EDIT: After some more research, I saw that quotes are usually defined as:

```
System.out.println(/"hello"/)
```

Do I need to do that?

EDIT 2: I removed the code that set the file's major version as java 4, still didn't do anything.

Comment: Are you sure that the version of Javassist supports the class file version of your currently used JRE? Besides that, I think that Javassist is too high level for a task as low level as Instrumentation/Bytecode transformation.

Comment: I built the bytecde manipulation JAR using java 8. The JAR I'm transforming requires java 7. In my transformer, to stop an error from occuring, I have to use 'cc.getClassFile().setMajorVersion(javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.JAVA_4);'

Comment: But I'm pretty sure javassist can do bytecode manipulation. The high level classes use the lower level classes.

Comment: You didn’t answer my question. *Are you sure that the version of Javassist supports the class file version of your currently used JRE?* Buried in your comment is a hint that your JRE must be Java 8, so the question becomes: Are you sure that the version of Javassist you are using supports Java 8 class files? The failure to read the `String` class indicates that it doesn’t.

Comment: I removed the 'cc.getClassFile().setMajorVersion(javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.JAVA_4)' line. Same error. I also compiled the bytecode manipulation JAR in java 7. Note: The jar I am transforming is built in java 7. And javassist has options to set the class file as java 8, so I think it should be able to read java 7 and java 8 class files.

Comment: I also tried setting the major version to java 8, and that didn't do anything.

Comment: OK, I had a bit more of a look. I couldn't find any solution online, so I had a look at javassist itself. I tested it by calling the cc.getClassFile.getMajorVersion(); and cc.getClassFile.getMinorVersion(); Javassist, depending on the classes that the jvm supports for it, will automatically set the class file to anything between java 3 and java 8. When I ran the diagnostic, it set itself as java 6. Could this mean that javassist doesn't support java 7 on either my JAR file or the jvm?